# How do Install Kivio on Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: ubuntu

It's not in the repository for 10.04 but I want to install it anyway. I tried installing a package for an old distro but I can't meet the dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A binary package is available for download [on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/+package/kivio).

Answer (score -1):

Download and save the .deb file from:

http://kivio.en.uptodown.com/ubuntu

Then click the .deb file to install.

Cheers!

Comment: Can you give a more detailed description of the linked content, and explain how it relates to the question? This will help ensure that this answer remains useful in the event the linked page goes offline. In addition, please be careful posting links in answers of this nature—they could be seen by the community as spam, correctly or otherwise. See the [help/behavior] for more information.